# Fit rotated square in parent square?

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I want to create a square which is 50% of the container (and auto height?). In this square I want a rotated square which points touch the parents borders (no overflow). It also has to be responsive.

```
.square {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    .square-inner {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        background: red;
        height: ??:
        width: ??;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use position relative and absolute , & percentage  to draw it

see the following :

```css
.square {
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 50%;
     background:blue;
     position: relative;     
}
 .square-inner {  
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        background:red;
        height: 70%;
        width: 70%;
        margin:auto;
       position: absolute;
  top:15%;
  left:15%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="square">
<div class="square-inner">


</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is the length of the side for the outer square, `sqrt(2)/2 * x` (≈ 0.707x) should be the length for the inner square. ([more about the math](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/SqRtOf2.shtml))

In sass there is no `sqrt` function we can estimate it like this ([more math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method)):

```
@function sqrt($square, $tolerance: .001, $estimate: $square/2) {
   @if abs($square - $estimate*$estimate) < $tolerance {
      @return $estimate;
   }
   @return sqrt($square, $tolerance, ($estimate + $square/$estimate)/2);
}
```

Your sass will then be:

```
$size: 200px;
$halfSqrt2: sqrt(2)/2;

.square {
    height: $size;
    width: $size;
    background: pink;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    .square-inner {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        background: red;
        height: $halfSqrt2 * $size;
        width: $halfSqrt2 * $size;
    }
}
```

PS:

```
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
```

won't give you a square unless the container is a square.

Comment: I went with the answer above, but thanks for your answer!